# Change object variable to String

Tags: javascript

I have do some **split** and when I test the data type by using **typeof** it said that It's a object

now I need it to become string or number data type and I try to use this

```
String(data[0]);
```

but instead of get a hold word I get only a first character.

What's the correct way I should do in this case??

Please advise,

Thank in advance.

Comment: did u try String(data);

Comment: The data value is "360" but it is an object

Comment: Yes, I did @KingKongFrog

Comment: .toString() It's still an object @JanJongboom

Comment: The value in the data[0] is something like "800" or "600" or "#slide1"

but its data type are object which make a problem when I use it

but when I have created a new var = 360 or "#slide1" It can use and its data type are number and sting

Comment: An array (of strings, gained by `.split()`) *is* an object if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Need a little more code. For example, this works fine:

```
var str = "300 #400 How are you doing today?";
var words = str.split(" ");
alert(typeof (words[0])); // Result: string
alert(words[0]); // Result: 300
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your data object is, you can use `.toString()` or `String(data)` typically to convert an object to a string.  If you have a string that is a number you can use `parseInt(str)` or `parseFloat(str)` to convert a string to a number.

Comment: I have test data[0].toString() it's still object and String(data[0]) is get only first character.

Answer (score 0):

instead of typeof, use instanceof

```
if(data[0] instanceof String)
{
    //it is a string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest code which is 100% equivalent to using those toString methods is just

```
(''+data)
```